# DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); replace month and day

Tags: .net, datetime, datetime-format

I need to change format of

```
this.TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

so it returns (for example) `25.02.2012`, but I need `02.25.2012`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring.aspx) with the specified [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) `MM.dd.yyyy`:

```
this.TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```

Here, [`MM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) means the month from 01 to 12, [`dd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier) means the day from 01 to 31 and [`yyyy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yyyySpecifier) means the year as a four-digit number.

Answer (score 14):

Little addition to [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182093/datetime-now-toshortdatestring-replace-month-and-day/2182099#2182099):

1. The `ToShortDateString()` is culture-sensitive.

From MSDN:

> The string returned by the
>   ToShortDateString method is
>   culture-sensitive. It reflects the
>   pattern defined by the current
>   culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object.
>   For example, for the en-US culture,
>   the standard short date pattern is
>   "M/d/yyyy"; for the de-DE culture, it
>   is "dd.MM.yyyy"; for the ja-JP
>   culture, it is "yyyy/M/d". The
>   specific format string on a particular
>   computer can also be customized so
>   that it differs from the standard
>   short date format string.

That's mean it's better to use the `ToString()` method and define format explicitly (as Jason said). Although if this string appeas in UI the `ToShortDateString()` is a good solution because it returns string which is familiar to a user.

2. If you need just today's date you can use `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: ...I need some more harder things, but this question was about date format. I hope we can solve my next question too ==

Comment: +1 great explanation about the mechanics behind ToShortDateString. Help me to understand it better, and also answered the question by recommending ToString for this case.

Answer (score 7):

```
this.TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.TextBox3.Text = String.Format("{0: MM.dd.yyyy}",DateTime.Now);
```